# Using JQuery to populate input field with first name and last name on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out a way to to populate a input field with first name, last name and @whateveremail.com (ex:john.smith@gmail.com first and last name being separated by . ) on button click? Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click & http://api.jquery.com/val

Comment: Welcome to SO - please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are different methods depending on the method used,

For get or set value of an input box you can use :

```
    $( "cssSelector" ).val();//get
    $( "cssSelector" ).val('new value');//set
```

See [jquery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
For trigger a event like 'click' you can :

```
 $( "#target" ).click(function() {
    alert();
});
```

or:

```
    $( "#target" )on('click',function() {
      alert();
    });
```

### For Example :

```js
 $('#clickBtn').on('click',function(){
       $('#result').val( $('#userFname').val()+"."+ $('#userLname').val()+"@"+ $('#userEmail').val());
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <label for="userFname">First Name :</label>  <input id="userFname" />
    <label for="userLname">Last Name :</label>  <input id="userLname" />
    <label for="userEmail">Email:</label>  <input id="userEmail" />
<button id="clickBtn" >Generate</button>
    <br> <br>
    <label for="result">Email:</label>  <input id="result" />
```

Comment: Thank you Mohammad... exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, I'd run a script that gets the text from your input fields from the first name, last name, and email. Then, take those, store them into variables, and concatenate them, so for example:

```
var FirstName = $('FirstName').val();
var LastName = $('LastName').val();
var Email = $('Email').val();

var ConcatFields = FirstName + "." + LastName + "@" + Email;
```

You would then write some code that stuffs this into the field you are wanting, and you could invoke this code on a button click for that control.

I assume that's what you mean, but your question is fairly vague, so reword it if you would like a more detailed answer.

Comment: Trevor - Thanks for your response... So I have a input field and a button and I would like to be able to have a user click on the button and it would populate the input field with first name, last name and @emailaddress. Not sure how to do this. Thanks again

Comment: buttons in html have an onclick event, you can pass to the event a function in a script that you would like to run, then you would just write the code to populate the input fields with JQuery selectors like what I did above.